# "write epipe" error when running child process only from electron

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I'm currently having an issue that only occurs when running electron and im not sure why. I'm creating a child process of stockfish using `child = execFile(stockfish);` everything works fine when accessing `stdin` from this child process with this script on its own, yet when I'm running an electron instance no matter where I call the function or what order I initialize them in, I'm suddenly unable to access `stdin` with "error write epipe"

What is causing this issue and how should I go about resolving this. I'm assuming this has something to do with the script being a child of electron of course but I'm lost.

Update:

I found that everything is fully working when packaging the project using 'electron-packager'. I find this very weird as the JavaScript error just suddenly no longer appears. Is my only work around for this really to build the project every time I need to make sure that child process is working correctly?

Comment: This github issue may help you https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24329#issuecomment-760699187, basically, try setting `{ windowsHide: false }` on execFile(stockfish). So it would be `execFile(stockfish, { windowsHide: false })`

Comment: This did not fix the issue. Nor is this issue relevant to me I don't believe. That issue is talking about the program hanging rather than a fatal error.